# Drowning in lots of old Ruby versions, Gems over flowing, how to delete EVERYTHING and start fresh?

Tags: ruby, operating-system

Have the latest rvm. I have a list of Ruby/Gems going back years, is there one command I can use to just delete everything? And start 100% fresh? thanks

OSX, 10.9.1

rvm list know  (Yipes)

## MRI Rubies

[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p484]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p195
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p353]
[ruby-]2.1.0
[ruby-]2.1.0-head
ruby-head

## GoRuby

goruby

## Topaz

topaz

## TheCodeShop - MRI experimental patches

tcs

## Minimalistic ruby implementation - ISO 30170:2012

mruby[-head]

## JRuby

jruby-1.6.8
jruby-1.7.6
jruby[-1.7.9]
jruby-head

## Rubinius

rbx-2.0.0
rbx-2.1.1
rbx[-2.2.1]
rbx-head

## Ruby Enterprise Edition

ree-1.8.6
ree[-1.8.7][-2012.02]

## Kiji

kiji

## MagLev

maglev[-head]
maglev-1.0.0

## Mac OS X Snow Leopard Or Newer

macruby-0.10
macruby-0.11
macruby[-0.12]
macruby-nightly
macruby-head

## Opal

opal

## IronRuby

ironruby[-1.1.3]
ironruby-head

Comment: I guess you *really* like Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rvm implode` will take care of that.